# No resource found that matches the given name, CircleImageView problem?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting an error message that says “No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘headerLayout’) in Xamarin.Android” on line 2 of activity_main.axml, but this is not on line 2, it is on line 31, and I did try to “Clean” solution, and then doing a Rebuild. I have checked the layout folder and does have “headerLayout.axml” and it is typed in correctly with capitalization match. I have provided the xml that I used as follows. If I remove the `<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView .../>` tag, it will get rid of the error message, however I was able to use this tag in the login xml layout, but it doesn't seem to be working on headerLayout.axml for some reason. I am using Karamunting.Android.HDodenhof.CircleImageView version 3.0.0 and the target framework is Android 8.1 on the project properties. How could I fix this issue?

**activity_main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >

        <include
        layout="@layout/include_main"       
        />

        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:background="@color/paleteroWhite"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerLayout"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**headerLayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/paleteroWhite"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/accountImage"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/account"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accountTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    />

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/paleteroAsh"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

If you need more info, I made a clone with the same problem for testing purposes only, please refer to this project: https://github.com/alextech1/AppTest

Comment: Did you add it in the dependencies?

Comment: Are you referring to LoginActivity.cs? I am not sure what you mean but I will post the code that I have there.

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about the CircleImageView nuget package, are you saying that, this has to be declared in a class?

Comment: Well yes, I think so. You know I thought this was Android, but now I'm realizing that it is Xamarin. So I don't really know. Excuse me :)

Comment: I noticed on their github it said to add it to the dependency if using android studio, but I also tried Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView nuget package and still had the same issue.

Comment: @Alejandro H, You can try to use lower case letters in layout.axml name, change **headerLayout** to **headerlayout**.

Comment: @CherryBu I tried that but it still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Nivaes.Droid.Hdodenhof.CircleImageView](https://github.com/Nivaes/Xamarin.Droid.Hdodenhof.CircleImageView) nuget package by Nivaes System in your project. Your project should target Android 9.0. and use code below

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
android:id="@+id/accountImage"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/account"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: so that means I should be using android 9.0 target framework?

Comment: I am pretty sure you meant Nivaes.Droid.Hdodenhof.CircleImageView, as I don't seem to find that nuget package you mentioned. Anyways, I tried it with Nivaes package and had to change target framework to 9.0 and still has the same issue.

Comment: First I have installed above nuget package in my project and targeted app to Android 9.0. It working for me. What error are you getting.

Comment: Seems like a really big issue, I removed the code instead and built it and no errors, but when debugging the error message comes back. No resource found that matches given name. But then in activity_main, I change headerLayout to headerlayout and gives me this error: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;

Comment: Just try to create new test project have same code with some icon, then see what happens.